# Node-cmd print Microsoft Word document

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, docx

I'm trying to print a docx file with opening Microsoft Word in Node.js. I'm using the `node-cmd` for cmd commands.

I'm using electron to make a desktop application.

Here is my code:

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');
cmd.run('cd D:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\"Microsoft Office"\\root\\Office16');
cmd.run('WINWORD.EXE C:\\Users\\ibrahim\\Desktop\\PalettenZettel\\output\\Output.docx /mFilePrintDefault /q /n');
```

But nothing happens when I run the application. "Output.docx" file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running both commands on the same terminal interface, if you do it like you are doing, the line

```
cmd.run('WINWORD.EXE C:\\Users\\ibrahim\\Desktop\\PalettenZettel\\output\\Output.docx /mFilePrintDefault /q /n');
```

just gets executed in another terminal which will probably not have its current working directory where you expect it to be.

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');
const proc = cmd.run('"D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE" /q /n "C:\\Users\\ibrahim\\Desktop\\PalettenZettel\\output\\Output.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit')
```

Also it might be useful to log your command's stdout and stderr to be able to debug it:

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');

function getDataLogger(prefix) {
    let data_line = '';

    return function(data) {
        data_line += data;
        if (data_line[data_line.length - 1] === '\n') {
            console.log(`[${prefix}]`, data_line);
        }
    };
}

const proc = cmd.run('"D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE" /q /n "C:\\Users\\ibrahim\\Desktop\\PalettenZettel\\output\\Output.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit')

proc.stdout.on('data', getDataLogger('stdout'));
proc.stderr.on('data', getDataLogger('stderr'));
```

Comment: Yes, nothing seemed in console